# Loop cursor twice

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a Cursor returned by dbHelper.getReadableDatabase().query().

I can loop through the cursor using:

```
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {}
```

Then I would like to reset the cursor and loop again.

I tried:

```
cursor.moveToFirst() // this return true
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {}
```

But this never goes into the while loop.

How can I loop cursor twice?

EDIT: OK, I get it. moveToFirst does exactly what its name suggests - it moves cursor to point to the first item. Then, if my cursor holds just 1 item, moveToNext returns false always. So the question is: how to reset cursor?

Comment: `if (cursor.moveToFirst())  do {  }
while(cursor.moveToNext())`

Comment: You should code it like that for the first loop too.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
cursor.move(-1);
```